# A no shipping option

Tags: expresso-store

Is it possible to not require shipping info, my client wants pick up one but when I remove the shipping fields it doesn't process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Default Shipping gateway and create a new method called "Pickup" without any prices associated with it along with your other shipping methods.

Then in your template you can use a conditional to check if the `shipping_method_id` is not equal to Pickup in which case you need the shipping details such as address, city, state, zip.